# Mesh not loading in Assimp

Tags: c++, assimp

To load in a mesh I'm using Importer::ReadFile() from Assimp.

In the documentation of Assimp it states that aiMesh::mVertices and aiMesh::mFaces are always defined. When I load in a stl file, the vertices are defined, but the faces are not. My scene only contains 1 mesh and the pointer that should contain the faces of this mesh is always 1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B.

The only similar problem I found online is this https://sourceforge.net/p/assimp/discussion/817654/thread/a7c953a7/ . He has the same problem only the pointer is a null pointer. He fixed his problem by using a newer version of Assimp, that was assimp 3.0.1264. I'm using Assimp 5.0.4162681867, so I think that would be okay to, but I haven't tried his specific version yet.

My code and output are the following

```
Assimp::DefaultLogger::create("", Assimp::Logger::VERBOSE, aiDefaultLogStream_STDOUT);


    // Create an instance of the Importer class
    Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene* temp_scene = importer.ReadFile( file,
      aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace       |
      aiProcess_GenNormals             |
      aiProcess_Triangulate            |
      aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices  |
      aiProcess_SortByPType            |
      aiProcess_ValidateDataStructure
      );

    //kill here the logger, just to see what has happened with the importer
    Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill();

    //check if scene
      if (temp_scene == NULL)
      {
            std::cout << __LINE__ << ": Error importing scene. Check if file exists ! " << std::endl;
            return -1;
      }
      else
      {
          int meshIdx = temp_scene->mRootNode->mChildren[0]->mMeshes[0];
          std::cout << __LINE__ << ": idx " << meshIdx << std::endl;
          std::cout << __LINE__ << ": mNumFaces: " << temp_scene->mMeshes[meshIdx]->mNumFaces << std::endl;
          std::cout << __LINE__ << ": HasFaces(): " << temp_scene->mMeshes[meshIdx]->HasFaces() << std::endl;
          std::cout << __LINE__ << ": ptr mFace[0]: " << &(temp_scene->mMeshes[meshIdx]->mFaces[0]) << std::endl;
      }

    exit(0);
```

```
Info,  T21520: Load C:/Users/Woute/Documents/2021-2022/computationalFabrication/files/balanced_die.stl
Debug, T21520: Assimp 5.0.4162681867 amd64 msvc debug shared singlethreadedsingle : 
Info,  T21520: Found a matching importer for this file format: Stereolithography (STL) Importer.
Info,  T21520: Import root directory is 'C:/Users/Woute/Documents/2021-2022/computationalFabrication/files\'
Info,  T21520: STL: Taking code path for Materialise files
Debug, T21520: UpdateImporterScale scale set: 1
Debug, T21520: ValidateDataStructureProcess begin
Debug, T21520: ValidateDataStructureProcess end
Info,  T21520: Entering post processing pipeline
Debug, T21520: TriangulateProcess begin
Debug, T21520: TriangulateProcess finished. There was nothing to be done.
Debug, T21520: SortByPTypeProcess begin
Info,  T21520: Points: 0, Lines: 0, Triangles: 1, Polygons: 0 (Meshes, X = removed)
Debug, T21520: SortByPTypeProcess finished
Debug, T21520: GenFaceNormalsProcess begin
Debug, T21520: GenFaceNormalsProcess finished. Normals are already there
Debug, T21520: Generate spatially-sorted vertex cache
Debug, T21520: CalcTangentsProcess begin
Error, T21520: Failed to compute tangents; need UV data in channel0
Debug, T21520: CalcTangentsProcess finished
Debug, T21520: JoinVerticesProcess begin
Info,  T21520: JoinVerticesProcess finished | Verts in: 6486 out: 4029 | ~37.8816
Info,  T21520: Leaving post processing pipeline
47/ idx0
48: mNumFaces: 2162
49: HasFaces(): 1
50: ptr mFace[0]: 1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking your log I guess there is only one triangle in your model, but 6486 vertices.

Are you using a point-cloud model?
If not: you can create a new issue-report for that model on our project-space at [Github](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/new/choose)